# List updates the variable from the Stateful Widget as well as local variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently running into an issue where I set 2 variables in `initState` (`_stringVariable` and `_listVariable` from the variables in the stateful widget (`widget.stringFixed`, `widget.listedFix`). I then update the variables that were initialised in `initState` in a `setState`. When I set the string, this changes _stringVariable but stringFixed remains fixed (which is what I expect) but when I call `.add` on `listVariable` it adds an element but also changes `widget.listFixed` and adds the same element...

DartPad with code
https://dartpad.dev/e2720e94fc074316cdcd6976f64b906b

Initial screen

[image]

After some button presses, I would expect the "Should not update" list to be [1,2] and should not have had any new elements added to it as this was not the array that I called `.add` on

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out!

The setting of one list to another using `=` is wrong - guess something to do with references to variables.

If I change
`_listVariable = widget.listFixed;`
to
`_listVariable = []..addAll(widget.listFixed);`

[image]